# In PHP, what can cause $_SESSION to become null?

Tags: php, session, null, session-state

I'm curious to know the various things which can cause the $_SESSION superglobal to become null during the execution of a program.  I have enountered a weird case where an existing session becomes null, despite the absence of `session_destroy` or `unset`....

Comment: Session not started, or manually closed.

Comment: Make sure no output is sent before you call `session_start()`...

Answer (score 7):

Without `session_start()`, the $_SESSION is null. To destroy it, you have to use the `session_destroy()` to make $_SESSION null

Comment: I can't thank you enough my friend, I was this close '' to jump out the window